# SQL query to retrieve all values for every column from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with about 200 columns, so I was wondering whether the following was possible:

Consider the following table, let's call it **PersonInformation**:

```
PersonId AgeCode NeighbourhoodCode DogFlagCode ...
1        5       8                 10
2        1       9                 11
3        5       8                 10
```

Consider the other table, let's call it **InformationValues**

```
Id       Value
5        21
1        22
8        Neighbourhood A
9        Neighbourhood B
10       Dog present
11       Dog not present
```

Now what I would like to do is create a view that shows this:

```
PersonId AgeCode NeighbourhoodCode DogFlagCode ...
1        21       Neighbourhood A   Dog present
2        22       Neighbourhood B   Dog not present
3        21       Neighbourhood A   Dog present
```

Since there are about 200 columns can I do this using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio using generating scripts? Or is this possible in plain SQL?

Here is the tricky part: *some tables that do not have the **Code** suffix cannot be searched and their values are in the column*.

I've been working on this a quite while, but I can't find anything other than doing it manually.

**Update 1**
As for the sentence before I define manually as "manually typing out all the column names".

Thanks

Comment: I think *"some tables that do not have the Code suffix cannot be searched and their values are in the column."* is wrong. Maybe you want to say tha "some columns that have the Code suffix [...]"?

Comment: Yes, that's another way of putting it, but those columns that do not have Code suffix do not need a lookup for the "true value".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that if it is an efficient way of doing this. It might be possible that there are some other ways by which it can be achieved efficiently. But right now I can think of creating Function for this. Here it is

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetCodeValue(@Id int)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @value varchar(100)
        SET @value = (SELECT Value from InformationValues WHERE Id=@Id)
        return @value;
    END
```

Now write your query to get the output like this

```
SELECT PersonId,
GetCodeValue(AgeCode) as AgeCode,
GetCodeValue(NeighbourhoodCode) as AgeCode,
GetCodeValue(DogFlagCode) as DogFlagCode
FROM PersonInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a massive number of `join`s, given the way the data is set up.  The idea is:

```
select pi.PersonId, iv_age.value as age,
       iv_nc.value as Neighbourhood,
       iv_df as DogFlag
from PersonInformation pi left join
     InformationValues iv_age
     on pi.AgeCode = iv_age.id left join
     InformationValues iv_nc
     on pi.NeighbourhoodCode = iv_nc.id left join
     InformationValues iv_df
     on pi.DogFlagCode = iv_df.id;
```

You should be able to continue adding the joins and addition flags for each of the columns.

Typing all this in is a pain.  You can use the `information_schema.columns` table to get a list of columns and generate the code either using a SQL statement or by dropping the names into a spreadsheet and using spreadsheet formulas to generate the code.

SQL Server can handle such long queries and the number of tables.  And you can put this into a view just by putting `create view <viewname> as` before the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a `Common Table Expression` here, certainly so because you'll have to reference the same table many times.

I must admit your question confused me a little - especially the statement at the end. I get the impression you want a recursive look up which really isn't possible without it being manually defined, after all how do you define wants your link and what's data to a script?

The use of a CTE should give you much better performance than just a standard repeated join, it's also a little cleaner. Here's a brief example:

```
with CTE as (
    select id, value from cte_data
)

select 
     T.Name
    ,A.Value
    ,B.Value
    ,C.Value
 from cte_test T
     inner join CTE A on A.Id = T.Val1
     inner join CTE B on B.Id = T.Val2
     inner join CTE C on C.Id = T.Val3
```

So to translate that into your example:

```
with CTE as (
    select id, value from InformationValues
)

select 
     PInfo.PersonId
    ,PInfo.AgeCode
    ,A.Value as NeighbourhoodCode
    ,B.Value as DogFlagCode
 from PersonInformation PInfo
     inner join CTE A on A.Id = PInfo.NeighbourhoodCode
     inner join CTE B on B.Id = PInfo.DogFlagCode
```